# How to add by row (using babynames dataset)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a ggplot of using the babynames dataset which shows a comparison between the percentage of girls and boys that have a certain name over a range of years. I'm a little familiar with adding by column which would look like babynames$boys + babynames$girls if I created a column with the number of girls with a certain name and a column of boys with a certain name. I'm a bit conceptually stuck so far so I just have:

```
 babynames %>%
        filter(name == "Jordan") %>%
        group_by(year, sex) %>%
        summarize(total = sum(n))
```

[image: resulting table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the percentages?

Try:

```
babynames %>%
    filter(name == "Jordan") %>%
    group_by(year, sex) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(both = sum(total)) %>%
    mutate(perc = total/both*100)
```